# Tests for libffi fail on LFS

Tags: linux-from-scratch, libffi

I am working on a Linux From Scratch project and I've run into some (potential) issues. In chapter 6.49: Libffi-3.2.1, I executed the "sed", "configure" and "make" commands successfully but when I executed "make check", it appears that every test fails:

```
MAKE x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu : 0 * check

...stuff...

Test run by root on Fri Jul 13 23:51:21 2018
Native configuration is x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

        === libffi tests ===

Schedule of variations:
    unix

Running target unix

...a lot of failures...

FAIL: libffi.call/va_struct3.c -W -Wall -Wno-psabi -Os (test for excess errors)
FAIL: libffi.call/va_struct3.c -W -Wall -Wno-psabi -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer (test for excess errors)

        === libffi Summary ===

# of unexpected failures    685
# of unresolved testcases    685
```

I've been following the book pretty closely, but maybe I missed something along the way. Should I even worry about this or should I just install it anyway and move on?

Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it. I basically went back and redid everything.

I usually I copy and paste the commands from the LFS book into a bash script and run it that way (if I can get a away with it). Well, apparently I forgot to write one for the diffutils package. But this seems strange to me because I wouldn't think that missing that script would cause issues with a test that seems to use DejaGNU let alone get me that far without any troubles.

Anyway, my LFS is up and running now!